# CSS Circle Division"Adding Central Circle for Final State Causes Integration Issues"

Tags: css

I have a cricle that is divided into 12 parts, where its part represents a mood state. I want to add my final 13th state at the center of my circle like the image below.[i want where the black cirlce is to have my final state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3sOU.png). I tried different approaches but they all mess with the rest of my circle. Any helpful insight will be very much appreciated.

here is my css file:

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(143, 119, 54);

    
}


.circle {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 35em;
    height: 35em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    width: 50%; height: 50%;
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;      
}
.text {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    width: 200%; height: 200%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(15deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(15deg);
    transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(15deg);
    padding-top: 20px;
}


.feelingText {
    display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  
}
.updatedText {
    font-size: 24px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
    
}





li:first-child {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-60deg);  

}
li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(-60deg);     
}
li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(150deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(150deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(210deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(210deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(9) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(10) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(11) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(12) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(330deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(330deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:first-child .text {
    background: green; 
}
li:nth-child(2) .text {
    background: tomato; 
}
li:nth-child(3) .text {
    background: aqua; 
}
li:nth-child(4) .text {
    background: yellow;  
}
li:nth-child(5) .text {
    background: orange;  
}
li:nth-child(6) .text {
    background: purple;  
}
li:nth-child(7) .text {
    background: cyan;  
}
li:nth-child(8) .text {
    background: brown;  
}
li:nth-child(9) .text {
    background: gray;  
}
li:nth-child(10) .text {
    background: pink;  
}
li:nth-child(11) .text {
    background: maroon;  
}
li:nth-child(12) .text {
    background: gold;  
}
```

and my main code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  
      <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
      function updateFeeling(mood) {
          // Update the text area with the selected mood
          document.getElementById("feelingText").value =  mood + ".";
          
          
      }
  </script>
<ul class="circle">
    
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('sad')"><div class="text" title="sad"></div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('happy')"><div class="text" title=" happy"></div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('bored')"><div class="text"  title=" bored">boredom</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('confused')"><div class="text"  title="confused">confusion</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('curious')"><div class="text" title="curious">curiosity</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('despair')"><div class="text"  title="despair">despair</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('anger')"><div class="text"   title="anger">anger</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('excited')"><div class="text"  title="excited">excitement</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('disinterest')"><div class="text"  title="disinterested">disinterest</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('inspiration')"><div class="text"  title="inspired">inspiration</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('interest')"><div class="text"  title=" interested">interest</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('relief')"><div class="text" title= "relieved">relief</div></li>
    </ul>
  
    <div class="feelingText">
    <lable for="feelingText"> I feel</lable>
    <input type="text" id="feelingText" class="updatedText" name="feelingText" readonly style="height: 30px; width: 130px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -9px;">
 
    
  
</div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Given how you've styled the segments (`nth-child`), as long as your central part is added at the end of the list, it shouldn't affect anything already there.

Answer (score 1):

- Inside HTML, add `<li class="middle"><div title= "middle">CIRCLE</div></li>` inside your `ul` at the bottom of it.
- Inside CSS, edit selector `li` to be `li:not(:last-child)` {...}.
- Style newly added li as:

  li.middle{
  position: absolute;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  }

Solution

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(143, 119, 54);

    
}


.circle {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 35em;
    height: 35em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li:not(:last-child) {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    width: 50%; height: 50%;
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;      
}
.text {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    width: 200%; height: 200%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(15deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(15deg);
    transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(15deg);
    padding-top: 20px;
}


.feelingText {
    display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  
}
.updatedText {
    font-size: 24px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
    
}





li:first-child {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-60deg);  

}
li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(-60deg);     
}
li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(150deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(150deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(210deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(210deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(9) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(10) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(11) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:nth-child(12) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) skewY(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(330deg) skewY(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(330deg) skewY(-60deg);    
}
li:first-child .text {
    background: green; 
}
li:nth-child(2) .text {
    background: tomato; 
}
li:nth-child(3) .text {
    background: aqua; 
}
li:nth-child(4) .text {
    background: yellow;  
}
li:nth-child(5) .text {
    background: orange;  
}
li:nth-child(6) .text {
    background: purple;  
}
li:nth-child(7) .text {
    background: cyan;  
}
li:nth-child(8) .text {
    background: brown;  
}
li:nth-child(9) .text {
    background: gray;  
}
li:nth-child(10) .text {
    background: pink;  
}
li:nth-child(11) .text {
    background: maroon;  
}
li:nth-child(12) .text {
    background: gold;  
}

li.middle{
    position: absolute;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  
      <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
      function updateFeeling(mood) {
          // Update the text area with the selected mood
          document.getElementById("feelingText").value =  mood + ".";
          
          
      }
  </script>
<ul class="circle">
    
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('sad')"><div class="text" title="sad"></div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('happy')"><div class="text" title=" happy"></div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('bored')"><div class="text"  title=" bored">boredom</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('confused')"><div class="text"  title="confused">confusion</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('curious')"><div class="text" title="curious">curiosity</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('despair')"><div class="text"  title="despair">despair</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('anger')"><div class="text"   title="anger">anger</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('excited')"><div class="text"  title="excited">excitement</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('disinterest')"><div class="text"  title="disinterested">disinterest</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('inspiration')"><div class="text"  title="inspired">inspiration</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('interest')"><div class="text"  title=" interested">interest</div></li>
        <li onclick="updateFeeling('relief')"><div class="text" title= "relieved">relief</div></li>
        <li class="middle"><div title= "middle">CIRCLE</div></li>
    </ul>
  
    <div class="feelingText">
    <lable for="feelingText"> I feel</lable>
    <input type="text" id="feelingText" class="updatedText" name="feelingText" readonly style="height: 30px; width: 130px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -9px;">
 
    
  
</div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```